# Retrieve data from elasticsearch based on certain value greater than or less than using python requests

Tags: database, elasticsearch, indexing, python-requests

I want to read data from ElasticSearch using python's request library. I have a start_time field in data and want to get records each time which are not previously extracted. for that I want to use a value that is greater than start_time certain value. In documentation there is a way to match values but I want values that are greater than certain value. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Syed, was your question answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [range query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html), which supports also [ranges on date-times](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html#ranges-on-dates). You can pass the query into the `body` parameter of the [search API](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.search) of the Elasticsearch Python client.

Comment: Glad it helped :) feel free to mark the answer as solved